# Python - 'map' results slower than 'for' setting same list of objects

Tags: python, list, dictionary, comparison, settings

I'm searcheing a fast way to set a big list of objects .  I know 'map' should be faster than 'for' but not in my test.

I also try to understand if it is faster to create a new object or to set an existing one.

Creating a new object seems to be faster than setting it up...

Can someone explain why this happens? Thanks to All

```
import time
import numpy as np

class myc():
    def __init__(s,_v):
        s.v = _v

    def set(s,v):
        s.v = v
        return s

def e_set(e):
    e.set( 10000 + np.random.randint(10000,size=3))
    return e


n   = 10**5
rng = range(n)

ta1=time.time()
a = [ myc(np.random.randint(10000,size=3)) for i in rng ]
ta2=time.time()
print("R1: created 'a' with new ", n , "objects with random values in " , ta2-ta1, " seconds")


tb1=time.time()
for e in a: e.set(np.random.randint(10000,size=3))
tb2=time.time()
print("R2: setting 'a' objects with random values in " , tb2-tb1, " seconds")


tc1=time.time()
m = map(e_set, a)
tc2=time.time()
print("R3: mapped e_set,'a' -> 'm'  in " , tc2-tc1, " seconds")
print("R4: values of 'a' > 10000 ? : ", a[5000].v , a[5000].v > np.array([10000,10000,10000])   )


td1=time.time()
lm = list(m)
td2=time.time()
print("R5: list('m') -> 'lm' in" , td2-td1, " seconds")
print("R6: values of 'lm' > 10000 ? : ", lm[5000].v , lm[5000].v > np.array([10000,10000,10000])  )
print("R7: values of 'a' > 10000 ? : ", a[5000].v , a[5000].v > np.array([10000,10000,10000])  )
print("R8: lm[x] == a[x] ? ", lm[5000],a[5000])
```

RESULTS:

```
R1: created 'a' with new  100000 objects with random values in  0.811359167098999  seconds
R2: setting 'a' objects with random values in  0.8541171550750732  seconds
R3: mapped e_set,'a' -> 'm'  in  3.0994415283203125e-06  seconds
R4: values of 'a' > 10000 ? :  [8444 4830 6574] [False False False]
R5: list('m') -> 'lm' in 1.0371909141540527  seconds
R6: values of 'lm' > 10000 ? :  [16584 11666 19657] [ True  True  True]
R7: values of 'a' > 10000 ? :  [16584 11666 19657] [ True  True  True]
R8: lm[x] == a[x] ?  <__main__.myc object at 0x7fbfcfa60320> <__main__.myc object at 0x7fbfcfa60320>
```

As you can see  **R1** is faster than **R2**

**R3+R5** are slower than  **R2**

**R4** shows that **R3** do not effects 'a'

But **R6** and **R7** show that after **R5**  both 'lm' and 'a' take effect

**R8** shows in fact that 'lm' elements and 'a' elements are the same

So for me ,  map a list of object to set it , is slower than cycle it with 'for',
and create a new object is faster than setting an existing one.

It's true ?

How can i aceive fast objects setting for big list of objects?

as @juanpa.arrivillaga said , i'm testing it with function:

```
def set_objects(list_of_myc):
    for x in list_of_myc:
        x.set(np.random.randint(10000,size=3))
```

Here the new RESULTS

```
R1: created 'a' with new  100000 objects with random values in  0.8763055801391602  seconds
R2: setting 'a' objects with random values in  0.8311254978179932  seconds
R3: mapped e_set,'a' -> 'm'  in  1.430511474609375e-06  seconds
R4: values of 'a' > 10000 ? :  [9557 1359 5255] [False False False]
R5: list('m') -> 'lm' in 1.031069040298462  seconds
R6: values of 'lm' > 10000 ? :  [12996 17379 18531] [ True  True  True]
R7: values of 'a' > 10000 ? :  [12996 17379 18531] [ True  True  True]
R8: lm[x] == a[x] ?  <__main__.myc object at 0x7fd64badd390> <__main__.myc object at 0x7fd64badd390>
---------------------------------------------------
R9: set_objects(a) in 0.8176069259643555  seconds
---------------------------------------------------
```

Yes, **R9** seems to be **faster** than **R1** and **R2**

Comment: "I know 'map' should be faster than 'for' " no you don't, because there is no reason to believe that, because it is generally not true.

Comment: Note, `R2` would be faster if you did it inside a function, and would probably be the fastest way to do this if you did it that way.

Comment: "I also try to understand if it is faster to create a new object or to set an existing one." It is generally faster to set an attribute than to create a whole new object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can you show me how to use a function in R2 process to get faster result?   'generally faster to set an attribute than' : I assumed it was so, but it seems not in this case. An example on how to set faster big list of obects will be appreciated

Comment: I mean put the code in a function: `def set_objects(list_of_myc): for x in list_of_obj: e.set(np.random.randint(10000,size=3)` then time `set_objects(a)`

Comment: Although, in this case, the difference between creating an object and setting an attribute will be very small, the time taken here is dominated by using `numpy.random`. IOW, you are concentrating on optimizing the *wrong thing*.

Comment: Aslo, the fastest way would be just to do `my_obj.v = whatever`, and not wrapping that in a setter (setters are very much not pythonic)

Comment: `v = _v` should be `s.v = _v`. Also, it's conventional to call the first parameter of methods `self`. This is not code golf, there's no prize for short variable names.

Comment: I am not sure if I missunderstand anything here, but why do you think map is the slowest? 1.430511474609375e-06  seconds means 0.000001 seconds in decimal.

Comment: @andreas 1.4us to map  but nothing is effected until calling list(map(a,b)) .  So the useful time is slower. In this case .   Always 'map' turned out to be faster in many other cases even after using list to wrap it.